# Replacing a substring (tag) in a given string in python based on dict

Tags: python, string, replace

I am trying to replace inside a json text(which i transformed to string via json.dumps) one tag like {Prio}. This tag i append to the end of the string.

The strange thing is the tag {name} is replaced but the tag {Prio} is not.
Can anyone hint me on my problem with this topic, please. Would be nice!

```
#insert function
def insert_str(string, str_to_insert, index):
    return string[:index] + str_to_insert + string[index:]


#my demo json.dumps
text = "{hello this is just a test {name}, and i want to replace}"
#add a new replacement tag
text = insert_str(text,", {Prio}",len(text)-1)
print("String added at the end of text:")
print(text)

#create a key value pair dictionary
key_values = {"name": "John", "age": 30, "{Prio}": "New York"}
# show the dictionary
print("key_values: "+str(key_values))

for key, value in key_values.items():
    text = re.sub(f"{{{key}}}", str(value), text)
    print("")
    print(text)
```

Kind regards
Robert

Expected Result:
"{hello this is just a test {name}, and i want to replace, {Prio}}"
should end up in:

"{hello this is just a test **John**, and i want to replace, **New York**}"

The **John** is correctly filled in the **New York** not.

*Note (background information):*
If you ask yourself why i am do this. For the final JSON format this is needed (i fill in placeholder which i am trying to replace with additional JSON code afterwards). I am auto generating JIRA-tickets based on different inputs (doors db + project specific inputs).

Comment: What's the actual string? Please provide sample input.

Comment: Its like the text....you can consider text as the dumped json file, there i have no problem. I just forgot to post the str_insert function as well. Sorry for that...

Comment: The issue is you're trying to replace `{{Prio}}` when you only have `{Prio}` in the text.

Comment: You shouldn't have `{}` in the dictionary keys, since the `re.sub()` call adds them itself.

Comment: text = re.sub(f"{{key}}", str(value), text) ?

Comment: Just remove `{}` from the `{Prio}` key.

Comment: but why is it working for the name {name}?

Comment: @RoDae Because the key "name" isn't enclosed in {}! You need all the keys to replace to have a consistent format.

Comment: I simple need to replace the line: key_values = {"name": "John", "age": 30, "{Prio}": "New York"} by key_values = {"name": "John", "age": 30, "Prio": "New York"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do simple string replacement in Python, you can use `str.replace`:

```py
>>> "hello mellow world".replace("ell", "X")
'hXo mXow world'
```

You are using `re.sub` which is a Regex replacement. This is adding complexity because `{` is meaningful in Regex and you need to escape them. But you're not actually using any Regex patterns, so you're getting this complexity with no benefit.

However, `{` is already supported by native Python string templating:

```py
>>> "hello {who}!".format(who="world")
'hello world!'
```

You can use that instead to make your code simpler and easier to debug.

However, in your case, you are actually attempting to do replacements not just on any string, but on JSON. Manipulating raw JSON this way is a bad idea. Whitespace is not significant in JSON, and various formatting tools and even file encodings can throw your code off. You should instead parse the JSON to a `dict` with `json.loads`, then do your replacements on the keys and values of that `dict`, and produce the result with `json.dumps`.

Your question is probably getting downvoted (not by me) because:

- The title is incorrect - you are not asking about doing replacemenets (which is already explained in other questions) but a very specific situation
- The question is confusing - there is not clear example input and expected output
- Your code is messy and hard to read, with a lot of stuff unrelated to the replacement

Comment: Sorry i am so stupid! Sure i have to only replace Prio instead of  {Prio} ! Why i was asking i have to generate jira tickets via rest api and i want to get templates and db inputs  puzzled together...The json.dumps and json.loads i am using already.

Comment: @RoDae I think my answer answers the question as you posted it, so you should mark it as an accepted answer (click the tick) so that other people can see that it's answered. If you are trying to set up a complex templating logic, you should post that as a separate question, because the SO format is not well suited for continuously changing Qs and As.

Comment: Thats for the very good answer! I could just solve the problem now!